# Netbeans C++ Build on local host need looong time

Tags: c++, netbeans

since today my Netbeans needs like 3mins or more to run my Code. (clean/run build)
I see the time i am waiting "Preparing to build on local host".
Aftert this everything is acting normaly.

The last thing i did was to "Reparce Project" in Code Assistance. And i turned the C/C++ Code Assistance on and off.

Why is my Netbeans now so slow?

In my Propertys:

Build: local host
Source: (no synchronization)

Answer (score 0):

Your Path environment variable might be having a lot of location or network path and your compiler path may be at the end of the path variable. Try to put the compiler location at the starting of the PATH environment variable.